# OpenMPI - MPI_Allreduce is taking too long

Tags: mpi, openmpi

[Note: I am sort of newbie using MPI, so applogies if I say something wrong / am doing something wrong]

I have these lines of code to make an Allreduce of two arrays doubles:

```
MPI_Allreduce (A, A_copy, size1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, rows_comm);
MPI_Allreduce (B, B_copy, size2, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, cols_comm);
```

The communicators rows_comm and cols_comm are created using checkerboard distribution of the processes.

An example with some data: executing those lines 10000 times, with size1=size2=2500bits and 2 processes per row and 2 per column.

If I run everything on the same machine, it's fine, barely takes any time.

Once I do one process per machine, all connected in a network, the combination of those Allreduce's take about 20 seconds. That's about 2 milliseconds per iteration, which seems too long to me, for such small amount of data. The average network throughput is over 500Mbit/s. If I try to scale this to a few more processes, the total time of the All_reduce's seems to increase almost linearly with it.

I am using MPI_Barrier to make sure all processes using the same communicator reach the reduce at the same time, so I don't account for any load balancing overhead.

Is it normal for the OpenMPI implementation of Allreduce to take this long? I can't use any other implementation, and the Allreduce is becoming a bottleneck in my distributed application. Is there a better alternative to do this? Note that I used this example with small data, but the data per iteration can reach some MBytes and the number of iterations can be thousands.

**Edit:** When sending some 2 Mbit per iteration, with 3000 iterations, I am getting a total of 70 seconds spent in the Allreduce's. That is about 23 milli seconds per iteration. If there are 4 processes communicating this data in the all reduce (2Mbits / ~500Mbit/s = 4ms), then I guess this time makes sense? So it seems like there isn't much of a point in making this distributed, since it's not scaling well enough with the number of machines and size of data, and since we don't have that many machines available (there are like 90, but only 10 are active apparently), a parallel implementation using something like OpenMP seems to be more appropriate. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: You seem to be making lots of `allreduce` calls each with tiny amounts of data.  As a rule of thumb, each MPI message takes a fixed amount of time (loosely called the 'latency'), plus a further amount of time which varies with the message size (loosely called the 'bandwidth').  Lots of very small messages is precisely the wrong way to work with MPI.  It's not entirely clear if that is a feature of your real code or only of your test code.  If it's only the latter, don't get worried until you have (re-)tested on the sizes and frequencies of messages typical of the real program.

Comment: I'm with @HighPerformanceMark on that. You need larger data structures to amortise the MPI and network overheads. Also, bandwidth and latency have very different influence on operations such as alltoall.

Comment: So your Gigabit Ethernet network is order(s) of magnitude slower compared to shared memory, at this stage, that should not be a surprise. You should run a pingpong benchmark between two nodes and measure the latency, and compare it to the 2ms of your allreduce keeping it mind allreduce might need several messages to complete. You can also run the same benchmark with a MPICH based library and see what kind of performance you can achieve.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes the size of messages are quite small, and so I can see that maybe these times are not as bad as I initially thought. I cannot group the reduce's in one, because the distributed application is supposed to solve a problem recursively (the current iteration needs the previous to perform other types of calculations).
I shall do some more tests with larger data and edit this answer.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I measured the latency and it was around 80 micro seconds. So I'm guessing message latency has some impact here, but would it have that much?
I'm not allowed to use any other type of MPI library (school project) but I'll try to look into MPICH and see if the problem persits. Thank you.